# system resets on certain apps

Tags: release-juno, pantheon, nvidia

I was really looking forward to juno, unfortunately this makes my system even more unstable than before with loki.

As soon as I click Epiphany, Pantheon will reset to the login screen, while I am able to log back in, there is no Dock, no top-bar no nothing... this does not happen with Firefox though, FF will just crash after a few minutes.

Also the additional drivers menu is not shown in settings, which was there in Loki. After manually installing software-properties, I can see the Nvidia 390 driver but no chipset driver (which was there in Loki).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, Yesterday I installed Juno, and quickly returned 0.4.1 Loki, I tried beta version Juno stable version like beta version nothing different.

ElementaryOS looking perfect but should be more update more stabilty.
But again I love Elementary and 0.4.1 Loki is perfectly working. :)